# Test Visual Basic Scripts behind an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

First of all I need to point out that I have never coded `Visual Basic` before.

I have an old spreadsheet which has some functions that are apparently written in `Visual Basic`. An example functions is:

```
Function Helmert_X(X, Y, Z, DX, Y_Rot, Z_Rot, s)
'Computed Helmert transformed X coordinate.
'Input: - _
 cartesian XYZ coords (X,Y,Z), X translation (DX) all in meters ; _
 Y and Z rotations in seconds of arc (Y_Rot, Z_Rot) and scale in ppm (s).

'Convert rotations to radians and ppm scale to a factor
    Pi = 3.14159265358979
    sfactor = s * 0.000001
    RadY_Rot = (Y_Rot / 3600) * (Pi / 180)
    RadZ_Rot = (Z_Rot / 3600) * (Pi / 180)

'Compute transformed X coord
    Helmert_X = X + (X * sfactor) - (Y * RadZ_Rot) + (Z * RadY_Rot) + DX

End Function
```

I'm trying to convert these functions into C. I have almost finished but what I would like to do is to build a visual basic project that calls the functions with various parameters. Then I will have a C project which uses the same parameters and checks that the C gets the same answers as the Visual Basic.

When I put the Visual Basic functions into a Module in Visual Studio I get a lot of errors. Firstly the comments don't all register as comments, and the variables apparently need to be declared.

Am I using the functions properly? Is there anyway to use them in code without modifying them? Could I use Excel to run test parameters through the functions?

Comment: fwiw, `application.Pi()` returns `3.14159265358979` (15 significant digits).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't write the functions, they were written by a previous developer and are considered the gold standard that we are trying to reproduce entirely in C. There are plenty of things that drive me crazy about the way they are written! Pi is declared like that in almost every one of the 25 functions, rather than once somewhere in the module.

Comment: VBA (used in Excel, Word, and other parts of MS Office) are not the same as VB.Net or VB6 or VBScript. The only place VBA works is in the Office Suite, which is why they don't work for you in a module in VB.

Comment: Ah, OK. That's a bit of a blow, but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to declare all variables that exist in that function. Try to add theses lines after the comments:

```
Dim Pi As Double
Dim sfactor As Double
Dim RadY_Rot As Double
Dim RadZ_Rot As Double
```

You can also specify type for variables that came with function, as well the function itself:

```
Function Helmert_X(X as Double, Y as Double, Z as Double, DX as Double, Y_Rot as Double, Z_Rot as Double, s as Double) as Double
```

Let me know if it works or if there is still some issue.